# Как написать Omit без промежуточного типа

Tags: typescript

```
type MyExclude<T, K> = T extends K ? never : T

type MyOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [Key in MyExclude<keyof T, K>]: T[Key] 
}

// Так тоже работает
type MyOmitAs<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [Key in keyof T as MyExclude<keyof T, K>]: T[Key] 
}

// type MyOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = {
//   [Key in keyof T as keyof T extends K ? never : T]: T[Key] 
// }

// type MyOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = {
//   [Key in keyof T extends K ? never : T]: T[Key] 
// }
```

Не понимаю, почему не работают закомментированные варианты, но или хотя бы вариант с `as`, ведь я просто перенёс логику из промежуточного типа в, грубо говоря цикл.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABBDMELQQPIFsCWAXS8491gRgJ4QCCAdugBYD2ZxAYgK4QAUAAgIYUBmjAlBADEyAKYATVI2RDGZVLSH5GqADbo4qMliyDdEAIqMRAZ3TytULAElkABxUjRFCFREQlq9ZogADFBgAeABUAGggAaQA+HwgAcxEyEQAnVABjCAB3DBpGdAhGY01YiAwAOm0oAGFaUyTGVPRjCA4XQls3IghbNIBrIuaVFS6k6naksxMIbhHpHyCYrjEXSgSIJMdqADd+n3CfCoh6aiSIEQAPDjsHA59bxqxNdGTuDlS3IOoxaggAbywoMzoBwALggtSK-wgYhMqRStjMtFB4LIsUhqWoVxETzEoPw1GoDi4WAAvgd0G13p9qAAFdbbEQZCAAXggAFlCP50MEqWEAOTQ4yw1Dw8y8iAAHwgvMBDl5kQO6LIphcVNBHy+tJE9MZLL+UCg6Mx2NBLxUxhEIRJWFu+0sUEiEAAaqgGRAFABxDAACUY+FBlHQ6FsxmBwGAjVSlFKACtjKVjrFgNAwCBgGB06AIAB9HO5vO5iAATWojBO1WhEC9yTc+drOYgqbA5PabMIAFEzqkVIxocEwlFmRAgqczk8yGImuEIAB+CCJTbJCBq9PNtzszl9iIjscTiA9ESEajcIcO3VYADa4QPJTIrY7XZ7IgC+8Px9CEUiAF01ZeD5+IGApJNhSraciQxiblO5w7k0L5Hieg56hAv7EN4cFvs0TTsve3a9uhQ79l+P5XoQ-6ASuIHrmg6AAIyQduCS7vhQSnr8F4kTee4HvBw4cLB3EYdBjGTjOc5aouarfkOKFkUBmZ1rWQ4mHklR8ZMCn5g2aaoHYxx5D8EBtgAjowHAqGEHbtA0EDElMMxSmwq5wJGZkOCiJjALkqjGLyFEtqkalNCy55YJZIgNAExmmSokVnFZ2I0WEVGBOq1B8gKQoirQcqRJElpQGFEVRWZsXxeIABMSUctR3JfOlMJwgiZBipKvKGvYWLiDl8qfumjzPK8lJfGxAIYCCYLoCkKJYBljXmEik0QgaGIdca7j4oSWhAf1SQvG8hlxeFCUjS4Y0iAtU2ostRriLiG0iES20UAN+2Fdi5UnTK50TZd5HpmA8kaQWTDjCsJwAMpPMG2ZA-WjagFgDrg5QHDrBAh6lmCBJeTU-qBsGobhoKUaxvGSSJtAwBcMYGTJIjTouoyxjY01IYQAGQYhmGEYk3GCZJsAzPdqz9OsscbiVCjgwJPEbMcwT3PEzGfPkymaZgEAA)

Comment: Please see [here](https://tsplay.dev/NVgqZm) an explanation

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks a lot. Оформите в виде ответа.

Comment: feel free post it is as you answer, I don't have russian keyboard anyway. Just wanted to explain whats going on here

Comment: @captain-yossarian Хорошо. Я кода посмотрел ваш, что я не внимателен и не заметил `keyof ` у себя)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ дан [captain-yossarian,](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/455649/captain-yossarian) но публикуется мной.

```
// @captain-yossarian
type MyOmit3<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [Key in keyof T as keyof T extends K ? never : keyof T]: T[Key]
}
```

В качестве ключа необходимо передавать не обобщённый тип, кортеж ключей.